# Time shifting with imported RSS feed into Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, time, rss

I am trying to setup a simple way of ingesting an rss feed into a Wordpress theme I designed. I have it working really well using 'fetch_feed' - all the rss items come through and I can sort them and display them how I need.

The problem I am having is the time shift. The feed I am pulling from is on an Australian server, and the actual feed dates are correct. The client server however I have no idea where it's at, but I set the time zone in the php.ini file as instructed by the hosting company, and yet all of the rss feed items are shifted by 13 hours.

Here is my code for grabbing the rss feed:

```
<?php // Get RSS Feed(s)
include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php' );

// Get a SimplePie feed object from the specified feed source.
$rss = fetch_feed( 'http://xxxxxxxx.com.au/events/feed/' );

if ( ! is_wp_error( $rss ) ) : // Checks that the object is created correctly

// Figure out how many total items there are, but limit it to 25. 
$maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity( 25 ); 

// Build an array of all the items, starting with element 0 (first element).
$rss_items = $rss->get_items( 0, $maxitems );


endif;
?>
```

And this is the code I am using in my theme to display the feed:

```
<?php if ( $maxitems == 0 ) : ?>
    <h3><?php _e( 'No items', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></h3>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php // Loop through each feed item and display each item as a hyperlink. ?>
    <?php foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : ?>
    <p><b>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $item->get_permalink() ); ?>" target="_blank"
                title="<?php printf( __( 'Posted %s', 'my-text-domain' ), $item->get_date() ); ?>">
                <?php echo esc_html( $item->get_title() ); ?>
       </a></b>
       <?php echo esc_html( $item->get_date('| j F | g:i a') ); ?><br>
       <?php echo sanitize_text_field( $item->get_content() ); ?>
        </p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: What does $item->get_date() return (if anything) without the formatting parameters (in other words, what sort of default value)?  You might be able to grab this value and munge it with strtotime() or something similar...

Comment: Thats a good question - I removed that line and refreshed the page and nothing changed. It's probably obvious, but I'm not proficient in PHP so I apologise in advance for my ignorance. I will try your suggestion of the srttotime option, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Kevin_Kinsey, I tried the strtotime but even though that didn't do the trick - that did lead me to the answer! Of all things, adding a simple line of PHP

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Australia/Sydney");
?>
```

Fixed it! Now all the dates come through in the proper time. Thanks again for your response and willingness to help Kevin!

Comment: You're welcome.  Your solutions kind of feels correct ... especially if you are in Australia and your readers expect to see Australian time stamps.  I suppose a "Holy Grail" might even be to allow them to choose their TZ from a drop-down list, set a cookie, and then have your plugin read that to set the TZ, but we could leave that for a later date. :-)